# Difference in behaviour between java and python

Tags: java, python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the list of all web elements by accessing top `//div[@class="Class1"]` using xpath in python.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="ID1" class="Class1">
<div id="SubID1" class="Class2">
<table id="Tid1" class="Class3">
<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class='Class4'>Samplecontrol1</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="SubID2" class="Class2">
        <table id="Tid2" class="Class3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class='Class4'>Samplecontrol2</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    <div id="SubID3" class="Class2">
        <table id="Tid3" class="Class3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class='Class4'>Samplecontrol3</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    <div id="SubID4" class="Class2">
        <table id="Tid4" class="Class3">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class='Class4'>Samplecontrol4</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    <div id="SubID5" class="Class2">
        <table id="Tid5" class="Class3">
            <tbody>`enter code here`
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class='Class4'>Samplecontrol5</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**Python Code:**

```
    def MainLogin(self):
 #wDriver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Eclipse/SelDriver/geckodriverWin64.exe')
 eleToolBox = webelement.FirefoxWebElement
 x =''
 index=0
 self.wDriver.get(self.URL)
 self.wDriver.maximize_window()    
 eleToolBox =            self.wDriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="Class1"]')
 self.wDriver.implicitly_wait(10)                   
 for item in eleToolBox:
     print(item.text)
```

In first loop `print(item.text)`  statement returns all elements

**OUTPUT:**

```
Samplecontrol1
Samplecontrol2
Samplecontrol3
Samplecontrol4
Samplecontrol5
```

Which is quite confusing for me. I was expecting the output `Samplecontrol1` values.

I try the same case in Java by taking `List <Webelements>`, iterator interface and it working as per my expectation. In java we can access value of sub-element by it's index to access it properties\values.

My confusion is why in python return all element in first iteration. What if I wants to iterate individual element is it possible in python.

Comment: Your sample HTML has only one element with `@class="Class1"` so the behavior in Python is no surprise. Are you sure that you use the same HTML for testing in Java?

Comment: It does not return all "elements" in the first iteration but the whole text contained in the one element which encloses the other elements containing the individual text parts.

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior of `find_elements_by_xpath`. Please note that Selenium support two different methods in python: `find_element_by_xpath` and `find_elements_by_xpath` (mind the plural elements). The first one will return first element, which seems to be your target. The second one return list of all elements.

You can read more in [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Hi Huy, yes I agree with you that it is default behavior but does this is different for Java & Python language. and I wants to find out the way by which I get same output for python code. I am asking this because I assume that the method should return same value irrespective of programming language.

Comment: As I mention above, python provide two methods. For your case, you may need to use `find_element_by_xpath` instead of `find_elements_by_xpath`

Comment: It does not a language problem. Selenium normally provides both 2 methods. I found that java also have both 2 https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/internal/FindsByXPath.html

Comment: Hi Huy, Thanks for prompt replay... I am more concern about my For loop print(item.text) statement. Print statement return all values in first iteration in python but in java it return ' Samplecontrol1' at first iteration.

Comment: hmm, sorry seems I misread your question. Your `for` loop is correct, and it should loop through each element. Just wonder if you do any setup to have `print()` function put everything same line (with space delimiter). Could you add another print() in `for` loop and check if it's correct?